# js MediaRecorder + ffmpeg

Tags: javascript, video, ffmpeg, web-mediarecorder

Help me, please. I record a video with javascript using MediaRecorder and then I store it on my server.

The VLC player plays the video well, but a browser has difficult to play it. A video recorded on IOS loads up to 2 minutes before the browser starts playing it(looks like the browser loads the video completely before playing it). A video from android doesn't contain the timeline, but starts much faster.

The video from android I fixed by fast re-encoding `ffmpeg -i without_timeline.webm -c copy fixed.webm` it works well.

I tried to fix the video from IOS with the similar command `ffmpeg -i long_started.mp4 -c copy fixed.mp4`, but the result is worse.

There are a lot of errors

**Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0;**

**Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1;**

The new video is rotated, has freezes, repeats and wrong time.

I've spent a week, but without success.

Answer (score -2):

I've manage to fix it. I used ffmpeg from repo, it was version 4.2. I'd tried to download from the official website the latest version (4.4) and finally I had success, this version fixes DTS, adds meta data and videos are played well.